# How can I move my B1/B2 visa from my old passport to my new passport?

Tags: usa, passports, b1-b2-visas

How can I move my B1/B2 visa (valid for 10 years) from my old passport to my new passport?

I do not want to carry 2 passports with me.

Comment: Alas, whether you want or not, you will need to. I did for many years for this reason. And then quite a few years later  I started carrying two again because of dual citizenship. I use a neck pouch at the airport so everything is always at hand (I also have a NEXUS card), otherwise it's deeply buried in my bag.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. It is not possible to transfer a US visa from one passport to another without making a new visa application.

Do not try to remove the visa from your old passport and stick it into the new valid passport. If you do so, your visa will no longer be valid.

Source: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html